# Why is my List(Of String) that is created within a for-loop not empty at each iteration?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, for-loop

I have a "master" List(Of String) that contains a few hundred strings that needs to be separated into n number of smaller List(Of String), with each smaller List being  the same length and then is passed into a constructor for an object which is added to its own list. To do this, my code looks like this:

```
Private Function GetListOfClassA() as List(Of ClassA)
    Dim listToReturn As New List(Of ClassA)
    Dim sublistLength As Integer = 38
    Dim masterList as List(Of String) = StaticClass.GetCombinedClassAInfo()

    For index As Integer = 0 To (masterList.Count / sublistLength) - 1 'This will always divide evenly
        Dim startIndex As Integer = index * sublistLength 'I know there's a bit of miscalculation here but at this point I think it's beside point
        Dim endIndex As Integer = startIndex + sublistLength
        Dim tempList as List(Of String) = masterList.GetRange(startIndex, endIndex)
        Dim tempClassA As New ClassA(tempList)
        listToReturn.Add(tempClassA)
    Next

    Return listToReturn
End Function
```

The behavior I am expecting is for `tempList` to be completely new on each iteration of the loop, so that each `tempList` created is `38` long. However, when I run this code, `tempList` is `38`, then `76`, and so on. The values of te 2nd iteration are being added to the `tempList` of the previous iteration which is then being used to instantiate `tempClassA`, and I have no idea why.

I have double checked that `startIndex` and `endIndex` are being calculated properly, and they are. On the 2nd iteration, `startIndex = 38` and `endIndex = 76`

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EndIndex is wrong because the parameter is asking for "count", not an end index:

From [List.GetRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> public System.Collections.Generic.List GetRange (int index, int count);

Try it like this:

```
Dim tempList as List(Of String) = masterList.GetRange(startIndex, sublistLength)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I guess I just assumed it was the end index!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
    Dim tempList = New List(Of String) From masterList.GetRange(startIndex, endIndex)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to post. I think this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the post, I can attempt this soon.